# Pass parameters to xml using ZEND REST

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest

Iam developing a REST service using ZEND, and iam new to it. 
This is my scenario:

The users will be sending their API key and password to a particular xml file, using curl, like:

curl -u key:pass https://my_site/api/v1/points.xml

and inturn, they will receive an xml response. I want to know how to send parameters to an xml file using REST in zend framework, which method i have to use (get/post/put) and how to get the response.

Did anyone try REST with ZEND and xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be sending parameters to an xml file, but to a REST service listener (which should be a scripting code in PHP). 
The result you get might be in XML

Comment: Thanks for the answer... can you point out to an example of how to send request to a php page...

Comment: Fine, i found a good resource here: http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/

Comment: Is it possible to atleast define a method like abc.xml, which i can use in the url, like: https://my_site/controller/abc.xml ? Can i have a controller something like xyz/123 ?

Comment: Found that Zend Regex Routes would be helpful in this scenario.